# What is the way in PowerShell ISE to let the user decide on what to do (choice equivalent)

Tags: powershell-ise

Is there a choice equivalent? I do not want to create a batch file but a script for PowerShell ISE. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Choice.exe is not a native PowerShell command but an interactive console application.

Try e.g.:

```
Start-Process -Wait "choice.exe"
```

Or use something like `Read-Host` instead:

```
$Choice = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your choice'
```

Also see: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2012/08/17/disabling-console-apps-in-powershell-ise.aspx

Answer (score 0):

*Generally*, you don't strictly need a **[`choice.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice)** equivalent in PowerShell, given that it is a standard executable that ships with Windows (`C:\WINDOWS\system32\choice.exe`): you can **simply call it from PowerShell** - ***except from the ISE***, where *interactive* console applications are fundamentally unsupported.

- Note: This fundamental limitation is one of several **reasons to avoid the Windows PowerShell ISE**, but these days the primary reason is that it is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are other reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md). The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

For example (in a regular console window or Windows Terminal):

```bash
# Prompt the user:
choice /c IRC  /m 'An error occurred: [I]gnore, [R]etry, or [C]ancel'

# Handle the response, which is implied by choice.exe's exit code.
# Note:
#  * An external program's exit code is reflected in the 
#    automatic $LASTEXITCODE variable in PowerShell.
#  * choice.exe sets its exit code to 1 if the first choice was selected,
#    2 for the second, ...
switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
  1 { 'Ignoring...'; <# ... #>; break }
  2 { 'Retrying...'; <# ... #>; break }
  default { Write-Warning 'Canceling...'; exit 2 }
}
```

---

PowerShell ***does* have a similar feature**, [`$host.ui.PromptForChoice()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice#System_Management_Automation_Host_PSHostUserInterface_PromptForChoice_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_System_Management_Automation_Host_ChoiceDescription__System_Int32_), but:

- its syntax is a bit awkward
- typing a selection letter must be submitted with <kbd>Enter</kbd>, whereas with `choice.exe` typing just typing the letter is enough.
- while it **works in the ISE too**, the prompt is presented as a modal ***GUI* dialog**.

For example (the analog of the above):

```bash
# Prompt the user.
# Note: 
#  * The "&" in each choice string designates the selection letter.
#  * The 2 argument is the 0-based index of the *default* choice, 
#    which applies if you just press ENTER.
#  * Similarly, the return value is the *0*-based index of the selected choice
#   (0 for the first, 1 for the second, ...)
$response =
  $host.ui.PromptForChoice(
    "Error",  # title
    "An error occurred:", # prompt text
    ('&Ignore', '&Retry', '&Cancel'), # choice strings,
    2  # default choice
  )

# Handle the response.
switch ($response) {
  0 { 'Ignoring...'; <# ... #>; break }
  1 { 'Retrying...'; <# ... #>; break }
  default { Write-Warning 'Canceling...'; exit 2 }
 }
```

To make the above easier in the future, [GitHub issue #6571](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6571) discusses providing a dedicated `Read-Choice` cmdlet or enhancing [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) (which currently only supports *free-form* input).

However, note that only a future *PowerShell (Core)* version would receive such an enhancement, which means that you won't be able to use it in the ISE.